# Using XMLWorkerHelper with IText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am new to using iText and I can't figure out how the XMLWorkerHelper class works. I'm trying to create a method that takes a string containing an html document, converts the html to a pdf document, and returns the pdf as a byte array. If someone can point out the mistake in the following code I'd really appreciate it.

```
Document document = new Document(); 
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(articleString);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();<br/>
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.parse(stringReader, stringWriter);
System.out.println("Before XMLWorkerHelper");
XMLWorkerHelper xwh = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
xwh.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, new StringReader(stringWriter.toString()));
System.out.println("After XMLWorkerHelper");
document.close();
stringReader.close();
result = baos.toByteArray();
```

The code I'm using is above. The html code is in the variable, articleString. The important part is between the two System.out.println statements. This is part of a web application, and the System.out writes to the server log along with any error or exception messages, but what is happening is that the application just seems to terminate without throwing any exceptions, between the two println statements. So the line "Before XMLWorkerHelper" prints, but not the line "After XMLWorkerHelper".

The jar files I'm using are itextpdf-5.4.0.jar, itext-pdfa-5.4.0.jar, itext-xtra-5.4.0.jar, xmlworker-5.4.0.jar

The html file I'm trying to convert is simply "Tester Article" and it is being converted by jTidy to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
Tester Article
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using the old HTMLWorker class from an iText 5.0 jar in place of the XMLWorkerHelper code and everything worked fine. The HTMLWorker code I used in place of the XMLWorkerHelper lines above were:

```
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(stringWriter.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is resolved already. If not, try removing the 
 code. If that does not help, try putting your stringWriter.toString() in an InputStream, then use the stream instead on parseXHtml in place of the stringWriter.toString()

InputStream

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringWriter.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

XMLWorkerHelper:

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, stream);
```

Hope this helps you or anyone who has the same problem viewing this

Comment: Hello, I am having same issue. I tried the above solution but did not work.